# SpringDataMongo MongoRepository pageable not sorted with geo-spatial method

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing a problem with sorting from  [Pageable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) with geo-spatial method in [MongoRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)

With the following code I am able to retrieve first `requestVo.per_page` records when `requestVo.page` is 0. However the list is not sorted by title.

Another thing I have noticed is that the same `PageRequest` object is able to give me the sorted pageable list with `photoRepository.findAll`. Any help is appreciated!

```
    LinkedList<Photo> photos= new LinkedList<Photo>();
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(requestVo.page, requestVo.per_page,Direction.ASC,"title");
    for (GeoResult<Photo> photoResult : photoRepository.findByLocationNear(point, distance,request).getContent()) {
        photos.add(photoResult.getContent());
    }
    return photos;
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that `GeoResult` is blocking the sorting. Working perfect when I just return collection of Photo.

```
    LinkedList<Photo> photos= new LinkedList<Photo>();
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(requestVo.page, requestVo.per_page,Direction.ASC,"title");
    for (Photo photoResult : photoRepository.findByLocationNear(point, distance,request)) {
        photos.add(photoResult);
    }
    return photos;
```

Comment: Thanks! very useful